# in reactjs, how to access the component method from other class by using ES6 method?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

in reactjs, how to access the component method from other class by using ES6 method?

I am facing a problem in  React JS. I'm unable to fetch the component method from other class by using enum.

Please help me out to solve this issue. 
I'm trying in ECMA6 format.
Thanks in advance.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Component} from 'react';

const Message = (props) =>
{
    const Enum = require('node-enumjs');

    var Days = ({
        constants: {
            Monday: {
                say1() {
                    return 'mondays are bad!';
                }
            },
            Tuesday: {
                say: function () {
                    return this.name() + "s are ok...";
                }
            },
            Wednesday: {
                say: function () {
                    return this.name() + " is the middle of the week...";
                }
            }
        }
    })
}

export default Message;

from Message component i have access to say() inside monday.

import React from 'react';
import {Component} from 'react';
import Message from '../../../message';

export default class Content extends Component {
    sai() {
        return(
        <div>
            <h1>{Message.Monday.say1()}</h1>
            <h1>{Message.Monday.say2()}</h1>
        </div>
    )}
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="page-title">
                <center> Content </center>
                <button name="press" onClick = {this.sai}>press</button>
            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

no error, but, when event rise in browser error like this: flows_content.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'say1' of undefined

Comment: What does your `Message` function must do? It is not `React.js` component, its a simple function which does not return anything. If you want to access `Message` methods you can simply create object with `Monday`, `Tuesday` like so `var Message = {Monday: {say1: function(){...}}}`

Comment: Why do you use an arrow function? `var Days = ("Days", {` should be `return Enum.define("Days", {`. Also: `Monday` has no `say2`, and  two `<h1>`s?  The whole code is a big mess.

Comment: It looks like they were trying to create `Message` as a [stateless component](https://medium.com/@joshblack/stateless-components-in-react-0-14-f9798f8b992d#.7w944lmyq) but got confused somewhere along the way.